# What does root slot mean in relation to vote accounts?

Tags: validator

How or when does a vote account get a root slot?  create-vote ? create-stake? or delegate-stake?
I encounter frequently:

```
Unable to delegate.  Vote account appears delinquent because its current root slot, 1458, is less than 1953
```

and

```
Unable to delegate. Vote account has no root slot
```

Comment: were you able to find a reason for this ? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: I think it had something to do with the first delegation transaction failing and having to wait and epoch to fix things... I don't really know what caused this.